# Перекуп- нормативне слово?

Tags: вживання-слів

В ЗМІ часто вживають слово "перекуп"/"перекупи" в означенні людини/людей, які щось перекуповують.

В СУМ є стаття словом "перекуповувати", проте немає "перекуп".

> [Перекуповувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/perekupovuvaty) 1. Купувати у кого-небудь куплене, добуте ним.

Чи нормативно вживати слово "перекуп"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не дуже нормативно позначати людеꙇ суто пнєвих чи з приростками іменниками від дїєслів, [бо вони](/a/4658/585) позначають речи, де дїя є частиною, або саму дїю без дїяня: як «схема», *пор.* маꙇже синомічне слово [*перепродаж*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pereprodazh). До іменників для людеꙇ варто додавати відповідні наростки (хоч, правда, тут нїчого не унормовано і досї суперечки). А так, перекуп нормовано вживати і досї ꙇого вживають не для людеꙇ, котрі цӧго робять.

Наприклад існує слово з тим пнєм, але з иншим приростком і записане ві словнику — [*покуп*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokup), а особу звемо [*покупець*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokupecj) (зустрічаєть ся також [*покупник*](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53407/173493.html)). Чому однопнєве мусить сильно відріжняти ся? Тому тоꙇ ж СУМ має слова [*перекупник*](http://sum.in.ua/s/perekupnyk):

> ПЕРЕКУ́ПНИК, а, чол. Той, хто перекуповує що-небудь.
>
> *Торговці — перекупники і спекулянти — прийшли пізніше.. їх прийшла величезна юрба* (Юрій Смолич, V, 1959, 8); *Сільськогосподарська продукція [на Кубі] реалізується державним організаціям, а не перекупникам, як це було раніше* (Комуніст України, 1, 1961, 70).

Очевидно, також [рідше] зустрічаєть ся і [*перекупець*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&safe=off&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C%22).